# How to Change a single strings color within a QlineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, pyqt5, qlineedit

I am working on calculator and when I click on "+" button I want the "+" to be in green color instead of white without changing the white color for the numbers

[image: Image of the calculator]

And this is the code of the button "+":

```
def plus(self):
    splus=self.QlineEdit.text()
    self.lineEdit.setText(splus+"+")
```

and to make my question simple and clear I want the output to be like this :

[image: what I want]

Answer (score 0):

You may try  to toggle the widget color with

```
    splus.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background: rgb(xxx,xxx,xxx); selection- 
    background-color: rgb(xxx,xxx,xxx); }")
```

To be fired by the QLineEdit's clicked event as:

```
    splus.clicked.connect(self.toggleColors)
```

Hope it works for you.